# How to put condition in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I want to show all scored records in score table and student name in student table if column "flag" equal "shown". Else, if column "flag" in Score table equal "hidden" I will show all scored records with student name = "Student". Finally show all that in order of time.

Here is what I tried:

```
select s.student_name if h.flag = 'shown', select 'student' as s.student_name if h.flag = 'hidden',
   h.subject1_score,
   h.subject2_score,
   h.subject3_score,
   h.subject4_score,
   h.subject5_score,
   h.exam_date
from Score_Table h
join Student s on h.student_id = u.student_id
order by h.exam_date
```

But that doesn't seem to work. What should I change?
Thank you!

Comment: Wait, are you using MySQL or SQL-Server? You use both tags, but it's not the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cASE` i evolves as,

```
CASE WHEN h.flag = 'shown'
```

It will check if the `f.flag='shown'` if true then it will select the `s.studentName` that is row value from table. And if the case is false then it will select the `student` as the `StudentName`.

You can also use the case as,

```
select 
     CASE WHEN h.flag = 'shown' THEN  s.student_name
     ELSE 'student' END AS StudentName,
   h.subject1_score,
   h.subject2_score,
   h.subject3_score,
   h.subject4_score,
   h.subject5_score,
   h.exam_date
from Score_Table h
join Student s on h.student_id = u.student_id
order by h.exam_date
```

Comment: it said there is sql syntax error at else line. (and I changed 'student' to 'hidden', still error)

Comment: is StudentName is the name of the column to print and 'student' is the value we will assigned in case of 'hidden' ? I see it print all the records with student, also for cases of 'shown'. Also, the exam_date is printed twice.

Comment: Yes `StudentName` is the column Name.And there is no possible way to selecting the `exam_Date` twice as it selected only once in the `select` statement. Can you post the query you are trying in question.

Comment: Yes, my mistake in comparing the value, in my table it is 'show' not 'shown', sorry. Your answer is my solution, many thanks for help !

Answer (score 2):

Your IF syntax is off. Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html

```
select if(h.flag = 'shown',s.student_name,'student') student_name,
   h.subject1_score,
   h.subject2_score,
   h.subject3_score,
   h.subject4_score,
   h.subject5_score,
   h.exam_date
from Score_Table h
join Student s on h.student_id = s.student_id
order by h.exam_date
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I'm testing on phpMyAdmin 4.1.12